# Review of Gas Chromatographs?

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, measurements, specific-reference

Could anyone suggest a recent review article or book on gas chromatography instrumentation? My interest is in the devices themselves, rather than using them for a particular application.

[This article](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1141631), "Gas Chromatography" in Review of Scientific Instruments is the sort of thing I'm going for; I'm just checking to see if there's a more recent or superior introduction.